# Comparing two CSV files and exporting the differences and similarities in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, automation, analysis

Hey all so I've been having some trouble trying to accomplish what I need with two separate CSV files.  I've found a few scripts scattered around the web that kind of do what I want, but not exactly.  I no longer have code that I've tried out as I've deleted different codes so many times that I've been staring at a blank py file for quite some time.  First here's the CSV files.

netscan.csv (contains computer names and serial numbers, has correct data, has models)

```
Name        Serial   Models
computer1   serial1  model1
computer2   serial2  model2
computer3   serial3  model3
computer4   serial4  model4
...         ...
```

computer_list.csv (contains computer names and serial numbers, has correct names, names that aren't in netscan.csv, no models, and serial numbers are wrong)

```
Name        Serial    Models
computer1   serialZ
computerH   serialN/A
computer3   serialQ
computer4   serialX
computer2   serialM
computerP   serialN/A
```

So what I would like to do is look at both files and if the value in the `Name` column matches I would like it to print the row from `netscan.csv` into a new file and do this for each row.  Afterwards I would like it to take all the ones that don't exist (computerH not existing in netscan.csv for example) and add those to the new csv under the updated, correct information.  Something like this:

```
Name        Serial   Models
computer1   serial1  model1
computer2   serial2  model2
computer3   serial3  model3
computer4   serial4  model4
computerH   serialN/A
computerP   serialN/A
```

I've tried merging, for loops, writing rows, etc. and I'm at a loss at how I could accomplish this at this point.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: @unutbu what I got from your code is essentially

```
Name     Serial    Models
computer1   serial1  model1
computer2   serial2  model2
computer3   serial3  model3
computer4   serial4  model4
computerH   serialN/A
computerP   serialN/A
computer2   serialN/A
computer3   serialN/A
computer4   serialN/A
```

So while almost everything is correct there are still duplicate `Name` rows from the `computer_list.csv` that need to be deleted if they were replaced by the correct info. So I would like to look for rows with duplicate Names and delete them if the Serial is serialN/A.  Hope that made some more sense.

Comment: Are there duplicate rows in netscan.csv or computer_list.csv? (By duplicate I mean rows with identical `Name`, not necessarily `Serial` or `Models` values.)

Comment: Neither, the duplicates are only in the `result.csv` and the duplicates I need removed came from `computer_list.csv` where the wrong information was.  I was thinking of something along the lines of getting each row with a duplicate `Name` value and then removing it `if` the `Serial` column is N/A, but I'm not too sure how to syntax just yet.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could merge `netscan` and `computer` DataFrames, then fill missing values in the `Serial` column with `SerialN/A`.

```
import pandas as pd
netscan = pd.read_csv('netscan.csv')
computer = pd.read_csv('computer_list.csv', usecols=['Name'])
for df in [netscan, computer]:
    df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.rstrip()
result = pd.merge(netscan, computer, on='Name', how='outer')
result['Serial'] = result['Serial'].fillna('SerialN/A')
result.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)
print(result)
```

produces a CSV file (`result.csv`) containing

```
Name,Serial,Models
computer1,serial1,model1
computer2,serial2,model2
computer3,serial3,model3
computer4,serial4,model4
computerH,SerialN/A,
computerP,SerialN/A,
```

Comment: This got me super close, but there are still duplicates from the computer_list file for example  
`Name,Serial,Models`  
`computer1,serial1,model1`  
`computer2,serial2,model2`  
`computer3,serial3,model3`  
`computer4,serial4,model4`  
`computerH,SerialN/A,`  
`computerP,SerialN/A,`  
`computer1,SerialN/A`  
`computer2,SerialN/A`  
is there a way to remove the NA duplicates, but keep the good ones?

Comment: It's quite hard to read data/code in the comments. Please edit your question to show the contents of `netscan.csv` and `computer_list.csv` which lead to the problem. Are you saying `computer_list.csv` contains more than one row with the same `Name`?

Comment: I've added the line `computer['Name'] = computer['Name'].drop_duplicates()` to the code above. I am guessing that there is a duplicate line or lines in `computer_list.csv` which lead to duplicates in `result.csv`. (AFAICS, If there are no duplicates in `netscan.csv` nor `computer_list.csv`, then there should be no duplicates in `result`.)

Comment: Yeah no changes after that.  Triple checked both files and they each don't have any duplicate names.  Only way I can think of getting out of this is listing the rows with duplicate names and deleting them if the serial tab comes up as N/A.

Comment: I hate adding the `mask` (see above) since I runs contrary to the way I believe Pandas *should* behave. But as a pragmatic matter, maybe it will help you.

Comment: That didn't do anything either, BUT I think I know why nothing is working.  Would the Name values in my netscan having a space at the end of them cause this?  I just noticed now that each one, except `Name` itself has a space afterwards while in computer_list there are no spaces.

Comment: Well, on second thought, `sep='\s+'` should remove all whitespace, so I'm still a bit in the dark. Can you post a snippet of your actual csv files (are they comma separated?)

Comment: They are comma separated and with your original code I had to replace \s+ with , to get it to work.  Still want me to post some of the csv files?

Comment: No, I don't think I need to see the CSV (but we'll see). I've edited the post above. How about give that a shot first.

Comment: That did it!  Was just reading up on strips right as I found out there were spaces.  Everything is looking good now I really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful for various kinds of comparisons

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#file_name = "list.xlsx"
df = pd.DataFrame({'List1':[1,2,3,4,5,5,11,4],'List 2':[3,5,6,8,9,3,4,9]}, columns=['List1', 'List 2'])#pd.read_excel(file_name, sheetname=0)
print(df)
#df.to_excel("list1.xlsx", header=True, index=False)
df['Intersect']=pd.DataFrame(np.intersect1d(df['List1'], df['List 2'])) #unique common in both
df['commonin1']=df['List1'][np.in1d(df['List1'], df['List 2'])] #non unique common items of list 1
df['commonin2']=df['List 2'][np.in1d(df['List 2'], df['List1'])] #non unique common items of list 2
df['1not2']=pd.DataFrame(np.setdiff1d(df['List1'], df['List 2'])) #in list1 but not in list 2
df['2not1']=pd.DataFrame(np.setdiff1d(df['List 2'], df['List1'])) #in list 2 but not in list1
df['1not2NU']=df['List1'][~np.in1d(df['List1'], df['List 2'])] #in list1 but not in list 2 non unique
df['2not1NU']=df['List 2'][~np.in1d(df['List 2'], df['List1'])] #in list 2 but not in list1 non unique
df['exclusive']=pd.DataFrame(np.setxor1d(df['List1'], df['List 2'])) # in a and not b + in b but not a
df=pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(np.union1d(df['List1'], df['List 2']), columns=['Union'])], axis=1) # unique all
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```
import pandas as pd
netscan = pd.read_csv('netscan.csv', header=0) # read netscan.csv and columns names are from the first row of your csv
computer_list = pd.read_csv('computer_list.csv', header=0)

# An inner merge keeps only row found in both pandas.DataFrame 
computer_match = netscan.merge(right=computer_list, how='inner', on='Name', suffixes=('netscan_', 'computer_list_'))

# Get list of Name of computers that matches
match_list = computer_match.Name.unique().tolist()

# Get characteristics of not matched computers
computer_no_match = computer_list.loc[computer_list.Name.isin(match_list), :]

# Finally, save everything to CSV
computer_match.to_csv('computer_match.csv', index=False)
computer_no_match.to_csv('computer_no_match.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: This only produced files that had Name, Serial, Model as the first row with no other information.